# How to filter with a exact string?

Tags: r

I need to filter a column called "text" in this database called "Amazon_2020".
When I use the code script below it filters words that contain part of the letters. For example, the word "acknowledgment" it is getting filtering words with -ment, too.

`Dt <- Amazon_2020 %>%          filter(grepl(pattern = "ableism|acceptance|access|acknowledge|acknowledging|acknowledgment",Amazon_2020$text))`

How can I get exactly the words?

Answer (score 0):

It is a case of partial matching.  Here, we need to use word boundary (`\\b`) to match the whole words

```
library(dplyr)
Amazon_2020 %>%     
       filter(grepl(pattern = "\\b(ableism|acceptance|access|acknowledge|acknowledging|acknowledgment)\\b",
  text))
```